React app - gh-pages does not find my js and css file - error 404
gh-pages does not find my js and css file. It gives a 404 error, as a result - a white screen.
enter image description here
here is my repository -
https://github.com/Beliy14/Soc-Sec-online
I will be grateful if anyone helps!
I tried to transfer the link to the js and css file inside the html, but nothing has changed.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You have only upload the files and folder that are in build folder rest folder is not required here then you can see you website or you can deploy your project in vercel, there it will create the build of your project and your website will be deployed in vercel

See https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/ for more about ignoring files.
dependencies
/node_modules
/.pnp
.pnp.js
testing
/coverage
prod
/public
/src
src
public
misc
.DS_Store
.env.local
.env.development.local
.env.test.local
.env.production.local
npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
I'm putting the src and public files in .gitignire, but they are still uploaded to the repository. I do not know how to send only the build file
